# how to quickly find the element that I want in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have a map that is `map<int,vector>`. When the vector's element was changed ,so the vector must  be sorted by some rule.And the vector maybe have many elements.My question is how to quickly find the element what I want.

the element may be shared by another vector.

```
class line
{
public:
  int line_id;
  string name;
  int capacity;
  int price;
  int cur_connected;

};

class no
{
public:
  int num_id;
   string name;
   string country_name;
   int country_id;


};

class lineCon
{
  public:
  line* l;
  int priority;

};
class lineCompare
{
    public:
    lineCompare(){};
    ~lineCompare(){};

        bool operator()(const lineCon &left,const lineCon &right)
        {
        if (left.priority < right.priority) //storage first
        return true;
        else if (left.priority == right.priority)
        {
        if (left.l->price < right.l->price)
        return true;

        else
        return false;    
        }
        else
        return false;
        }
};
line *l1 = new line();
line *l2 = new line();
line *l3 = new line();

lineCon lc1= new lineCon();
lineCon lc2= new lineCon();
lineCon lc3= new lineCon();
lineCon lc4= new lineCon();

lc1->l=l1;
lc1->priority=2;
lc2->l=l2;
lc2->priority=3;
lc3->l=l3;
lc3->priority=2;

lc4->l=l3;
lc4->priority=2;

vectory<lineCon> vec;
vec.push_back(lc1);
vec.push_back(lc2);
vec.push_back(lc3);
sort(vec.begin(),vec.end(),lineCompare());

vectory<lineCon> vec2;
vec2.push_back(lc4);
sort(vec2.begin(),vec2.end(),lineCompare());

map<int,vector<lineCon> > h;
h.insert(make_pair(2,vec))
h.insert(make_pair(3,vec2))
```

when l3->price=0 was changed
then it will

```
sort(vec.begin(),vec.end(),lineCompare());
sort(vec2.begin(),vec2.end(),lineCompare());
```

when the element was changed,vector must be sorted.and when the element was invalid,I have to check every element which is valid.

the vector looks like seats of train.I want to quickly find which seat can be sited.

what is your best way to deal it.

Comment: how to find the vector you want, or how to find the element within the vector?  can there be repeats?  can you elaborate?

Comment: sorry,I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to retrieve the vectors containing your `line`.

If you may change `line` to have some sort of back references to its container, then you will have the info immediately. These reference has to be filled when inserting line in each of its parent.

```
class line
{
public:
  int line_id;
  string name;
  int capacity;
  int price;
  int cur_connected;

  std::vector<lineCon> owners; // choose the more relevant between
                               // direct owner `lineCon`,
                               // final container vector<lineCon>
                               // or key of the map 
};
```

If you cannot modify `line`, then you may do a `std::map` with `line*` as key (or `line_id` ?) and its owners as values.

```
std::map<line*, std::vector<lineCon>>
```

Comment: thanks,give me some idea,but it can't solve the problem that how to quickly find the element of vector. the vector look like seats of train.I want to quickly find which seat can be sited.

Comment: @gougou: you have `lower_bound` for that as the element are sorted... But you consider that this function doesn't meet your requirement.

Comment: why it doesn't meet the requirement?

Comment: I mean that it's not only that the element are sorted.